# Problem with React everytime I install something

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, dependencies

I hope everyone is doing well.
Im having issues with React. I'm new using it as a way to create websites. I create my GitHub repository, open VSCode, type "npx create-react-app name-app", and then I start coding my components, changing the App.js: well, changing everything that I need.

The problem is that, whenever I install something else (like Axios, or in this case, react-router-dom), my project crashes. In this particular clase, I have this error: **Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported** and, when I see the browser,it says that Firefox couldn't connect to the server.

This is that part of the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "name-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.16.0",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Thanks in advance!I'm really looking forward to finish a react project, but everytime I add something it crashs and it's making me doubt a lot of my abilities.

I've tried reinstalling node modules and package-lock, and creating new repositories to see if there was a problem just with those, but I keep creating new ones that crash as well when I add something. Tailwind CSS and Bootstrap do not make the app crash, they work perfectly.

Comment: What Node version are you using? with what you have in according to your dependencies, its best to use Node version 18. Try install `nvm` in your terminal and play around with the node version and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Thank you so much Taiwei, that fixed all the issues!